# How to use onMouseEnter within reactstrap?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactstrap

I have a component that renders a reactstrap table and within the render I have map function of a state of clients that gets rendered as table rows.

Within each table row there is a component(separate button component that just open up a modal) that gets rendered within the map function.I want to use the onMouseEnter to determine which row I am currently at(with cursor) and when I click on the button component.Now the modal component just opens up the same for all rows.

The idea is that lets say I load 4 clients and map through them,when I do I render a table row for each client within the map.Along with this map function I also add a button component(separate component) as a td tag for each tr that gets rendered.

I want to use onMouseEnter to know which one I am at in the row.
So when mouse is hovering over second row(position 1 in clients array) I want to be able to know at which row I am at.

Then I want to pass this row index(which I need to get somehow?) to the button component(same component just rendered 4 times for each client row) and when button component renders I can get this index from props.

.....Please know I am a big react noob just trying to figure this out
I am using a list/array to render the table depending from data I get from a API so it can be 6 clients or a 100 you know?

Hahah just asking for advise 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React has an abstraction to vanilla DOM events called Synthetic events. Lucky for you, the Synthetic event you're looking for has the same name, "onMouseEnter".

```
<span onMouseEnter={(event)=>console.log('ENTERED!')} />
```

You can get read up on most of them here
https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html

Comment: Holy smokes!!! Thank you so much.....I did read that documentation but somehow got stuck....Fresh day and started using your example and wooola!!! THanks man